# Does NDISUIO have a limit on the number of EtherTypes to listen for

Tags: windows-ce, ndis

I've been asked to look into using raw ethernet frames on WinCE 7.0

As far as I can tell I need to call `CreateFile` and use `IOCTL_NDISUIO_SET_ETHER_TYPE` for every ether type I want to receive.

I've tested this calling create file multiple times and using different ether types and it seems that I can create as many as I want but calling `ReadFile` on more than 3 simultaneously results in **Error Code 31** (From GetLastError)

Am I wrong in my assumptions or is there a limit to the number of Ether Types I can listen to using NDISUIO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defined in ndisuio.h

```
#define MAX_OPEN_DEVICE_COUNT ( 4 )
```